# How to execute selenium cucumber test cases in different environment at the same time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have 100 test cases in selenium-cucumber framework as part of regression suite. I need to execute 50 tests in qa environment and 50 in dev environment at the same time (in the same jenkins build). How can I achieve this? I have two property files, one is for dev and other one is for qa.

Comment: How do you determine today which cases need to be executed where?

Answer (score 0):

you can use data-provider config (testNG), how do you run this tests?
I imagine you have some jenkins job that is running the tests. The tests don't need to know where are they running you just need to pass IP or URL from the job.
Also in java you can create a factory that give the test the correct URL to run on.